# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne') | apollo-server-express | sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I'm being driven slowly mad by this issue.

Using a local Apollo Server instance being accessed by Apollo Studio, I am attempting a simple mutation, createUser, and this issue is arising. What have I misunderstood?

Am I incorrectly consuming the context I provided in the server's creation? Or incorrectly accessing this model, maybe? Not sure!

Here is the error showing in Apollo Studio, followed by my files:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createUser"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')",
            "    at Object.createUser (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/graphql/resolvers/user.js:22:46)",
            "    at field.resolve (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/utils/schemaInstrumentation.js:56:26)",
            "    at executeField (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:479:20)",
            "    at /Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:375:22",
            "    at promiseReduce (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/promiseReduce.js:23:9)",
            "    at executeFieldsSerially (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:371:43)",
            "    at executeOperation (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:345:14)",
            "    at execute (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:136:20)",
            "    at execute (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:205:48)",
            "    at processGraphQLRequest (/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/PassTheArt/pass-the-art-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:148:34)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

```
// ./server.js
require('dotenv').config();
import express from 'express';
import db from './db';
import resolvers from './graphql/resolvers';
import typeDefs from './graphql/typeDefs';
import http from 'http';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';

async function startApolloServer(){
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs, 
        resolvers,
        introspection: true,
        playground: true,
        context: async() => {
            return {
                db
            }
        }
    });
    
    const app = express();
    const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    
    server.start().then(res=>{
        server.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/graphql'});
        db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(async()=>{
            console.log('database synced');
        });
        httpServer.listen({port: process.env.PORT}, ()=>{
            console.log(`Apollo Server is ready at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/graphql`)
        })
    })
}

startApolloServer();
```

```
// ./graphql/resolvers/user.js
import { UserInputError } from "apollo-server-express";
import { Op } from "sequelize";

export default {
    Query: {
        // ! This query is for the logged in user
        me: async(root, args, {db, me}, info) => {
            const user = await db.user.findByPk(me.id);
            return user;
        },
        // ! This query returns all users
        users: async(root, args, {db}, info) => {
            const users = await db.user.findAll();
            if (!users) throw new Error('No users found')
            return users;
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        // ! This mutation creates a new user
        createUser: async(root, {input}, {db}) => {
            const {email} = input;
            const userExists = await db.user.findOne({
                where: {
                    [Op.eq]: [{email}]
                }
            })
            if (userExists) {
                throw new Error('A user with this email already exists');
            }
            const user = await db.user.create({
                ...input
            });
            return user;
        },
        // ! 
        login: async(root, {email, password}, {db}, info) => {
            const user = await db.user.findOne({
                where: {email},
            });
            if(!user) throw new UserInputError(`User ${email} does not exist`);
            const isValid = await user.validatePassword(password);
            if(!isValid) throw new UserInputError(`Password is incorrect`);
            return user;
            
        }
    } 
}
```

```
// ./db.js
require('dotenv').config();
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
        port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
);

sequelize.authenticate()
.then(console.log(()=>'Connection has been established successfully.'))
.catch(e=>console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', e));

const modelPath = path.join(__dirname, '/models');
fs.readdirSync(path.join(modelPath))
    .filter((file)=>
        file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    )
    .forEach((file)=>{
        const model = sequelize.define(path.join(modelPath, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });
    
Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName)=>{
    if (db[modelName].associate){
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

```
// ./models/User.js
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define(
        'user',
        {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true, 
                validate: {
                    isEmail: {
                        args: true,
                        msg: 'Invalid email'
                    },
                },
            },
            password: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            freezeTableName: true,
        },
    );

    User.findByLogin = async (login) => {
        let user = await User.findOne({
            where: {email: login},
        });
        return user;
    };

    User.beforeCreate(async (user) => {
        if (user.password){
            user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash();
        }
    });

    User.prototype.updatePasswordHash = async function (password) {
        const saltRounds = 10;
        return await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
    };

    User.prototype.updatePasswordHash = async function () {
        const saltRounds = 10;
        return await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds);
    };

    User.prototype.validatePassword = async function (password) {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    };

    return User;
}
```

```
// ./graphql/typedefs/User.js
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

export default gql`
    #---------------------------------------
    # TYPES
    #---------------------------------------
   
    type User {
        id: ID
        name: String!
        email: String!
    }

    #---------------------------------------
    # QUERIES
    #---------------------------------------
    
    extend type Query {
        me: User
        users: [User!]
    }

    #---------------------------------------
    # MUTATIONS
    #---------------------------------------

    extend type Mutation {
        createUser(input: CreateUserInput!): User!
        login(email: String!, password: String!): User!
        logout: User!
    }

    #---------------------------------------
    # MUTATIONS
    #---------------------------------------

    input CreateUserInput {
        name: String!
        email: String!
        password: String!
    }
`
```

Comment: Did you check `db.user` and `email` are correct?

Comment: @Anatoly Can you please clarify "correct"?

Comment: I mean `db.user` there is an actual Sequelize model and `email` is non-empty string

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you for clarifying. Yes, there is a model at db.user, and email *should* be a non-empty string. email value is being provided during an Apollo Studio mutation; it's that mutation which throws the error.

Comment: The error says that `db.user` is undefined in your resolver.

Comment: @robertklep ```db.user``` should be provided by Apollo as context; see ```server.js``` above. Have I made a mistake in providing ```db.user``` via context?

Comment: At first glance it looks alright, and if `db` wasn't being provided in the context the error would have been different. Does `db.user.findOne()` work outside of your resolver?

Comment: @robertklep ```console.log(db.user)``` seems to work, but ```console.log(db.user.findOne())``` logs this error to the console: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')```. 

It's apparent that ```findOne()``` isn't located on ```db.user```. I've tried to explicitly declare this member function within my model, however the same error persists. Shouldn't sequelize it be automatically populating my models with this member function? (I may be totally wrong on that assumption)

Comment: @robertklep Something which adds to the challenge of debugging is, admittedly, I'm not wholly sure how to debug this particular stack; ```server.js``` starts a graphql endpoint but does not provide any sort of client except the stock Apollo Server splash page that leads to Apollo Studio, and that page does not show my console logs.

Comment: The error still says that `db.user` is undefined, which doesn't make a lot of sense unless it's some sort of proxy or a getter of some sorts. I haven't worked with Sequelize for a while but I'm pretty sure `Model.findOne()` should exist.
I would suggest scaling back your code to a bare minimum to check if your database setup is actually correct (hence my question about `db.user.findOne` working outside of your resolver).

Comment: Is `console.log(db.user)` show a real Sequelize model instance?

Comment: @Anatoly Ah, you both are correct, ```db.user``` *is* ```undefined```

Comment: I've run ```console.log(db)``` and received a very large object, then ```console.log(db.user)``` returns ```undefined```

Comment: And, ```console.log(db.sequelize.models)``` properly returns the path to the model declaration file: ```{
  '/Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/**projectname**/models/User.js': /Volumes/T7 Touch/Projects/**projectname**/models/User.js
}```

Comment: I'm thinking there is an error in ```db.js``` (code is above). It looks like the model isn't being imported, but rather the *path* string leading to the model instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get `db.user.findOne` defined properly. I was not properly using `sequelize.define()` in `db.js`, and I have now rewritten the pesky section as such:

```
const modelPath = path.join(__dirname, '/models');
fs.readdirSync(path.join(modelPath))
    .filter((file)=>
        file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    )
    .forEach((file)=>{
        const modelFile = path.join(modelPath, file);
        const modelExport = require(modelFile);
        if (! modelExport) throw new Error ('Error accessing model declaration file: ', modelFile)
        const model = modelExport.default(sequelize);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct `where` option from

```js
where: {
  [Op.eq]: [{email}]
}
```

to

```js
where: {
  email
}
```

just like you did in the `login` mutation.

Comment: I have made the change you've recommended within ```./graphql/resolvers/user.js```, however the error persists.

Comment: Do you have the same error in `login`?

Comment: I have just ran the ```login``` mutation, and the same error is occurring, yes

Comment: Also, it seems that your recommendation may have worked in an earlier version, but is no longer supported. I received the following error: 

```"message": "Support for {where: 'raw query'} has been removed."```

Comment: There is no raw query in suh condition: `where: { email: email}`